# bookmarklet to parse id in a url and reconstruct a new one

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have an evernote web url

> https://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/client/snv?noteGuid=18fd15e2-9581-47db-8140-0b94dc3b9f96&noteKey=6846ea69a9afa4f5

I want to convert it with javascript to a desktop app url

> evernote:///view/s5/18fd15e2-9581-47db-8140-0b94dc3b9f96/18fd15e2-9581-47db-8140-0b94dc3b9f96/

the question boils down to how can I get the id following `noteGuid=` and before `&noteKey`

**EDIT**

I found a neat way to parse out the noteGuid

```
var noteGuid = location.search.match(new RegExp("noteGuid" + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"))[1];
```

Comment: There should be many existing questions on site about how to parse query parameters out of a url

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.substring()` and `indexOf()`

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
function getParameter(startAt, endAt){
  var val = input.value;
  var id = val.substring(val.indexOf(startAt)+startAt.length+1, val.indexOf(endAt));
  var url = "evernote:///view/s5/"+id+"/";
  console.log(url);
}
```

```html
<input value="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/client/snv?noteGuid=18fd15e2-9581-47db-8140-0b94dc3b9f95&noteKey=6846ea69a9afa4f5"><button onclick="getParameter('?noteGuid', '&noteKey')">Parse</button>
```

You can use `window.location` to retrieve the current URL.